# Let $\ddot x=2x$. If $\dot x$ is $0$ when $x=1$. Find $\dot x(x=3)$.

Tags: integration, physics, proof-explanation

I was given this problem in a physics class, and below is the answer by the professor. ($x$ is position, $v=\dot x$ is velocity, $a=\dot v=\ddot x$ acceleration).

> Let $a=2x$. If $v$ is $0$ when $x=1$. Find $v$ when $x=3$.

Professor's answer:

> We can rewrite $a=\frac {dv}{dt}=\frac{dv}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac {dv}{dx}v(t)$, thus $$\frac {dv}{dx}v(t)=2x\iff vdv=2xdx\iff \int_0^vvdv=2\int_1^3xdx\iff \frac{v^2(3)}2=8\\
> \therefore v(3)=\pm2$$

I belive this answer is an atrocity: He allegedly arrived at the correct answer, but I have no idea why: Besides the horrendous differential 'tricks', why can he integrate on one side from "$ 0$ to $v$" and on the other from "$0$ to $3$"?

Is there anyway to solve this in a mathematically correct manner (I really don't want to use the differential thing he's doing).

I tried to solve this solving the DE $\ddot x = 2x$, getting $x=ce^{\sqrt 2 t}+de^{-\sqrt 2 t}$, but I think the initial condition given is insufficient to determine $c,d$.

Comment: I think you made a mistake when copying : it should probably be $\int_1^3 vdv$. Otherwise, it is actually possible to make sense of the $dv$ and $dx$ tricks, but if you want an elementary solution, you can explicitly solve the differential equation and plug in the condition.

Comment: @CaptainLama I added that in: my first thought was solving the DE, but it seems I need an additional initial condition. I'm pretty certain I copied it correctly (I checked with a mate), but it may have been an error from my prof. Is there any way to make sense of the $dv,dx$ manipulation?

Comment: Ah no, my bad, I get what your teacher is saying. It's just formulatd like a physicist would... I'll write an answer.

Comment: Would the downvoter explain the vote?

Comment: x=ce^√2 t+de^−√2 t is quivalent to x = A cosh (√2 t) + B sinh(√2 t),  If you set A = 1 and B = 0, then x(0) = 1 and v(0) = 0.

Comment: (v^2(3))/2 = 8 ==> v = ± 4

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic polynomial is $z^2-2$. Hence the general solution of your equation is $$x(t) = Ae^{\sqrt{2}t}+Be^{-\sqrt{2}t}.$$ Then $$v(t) = x'(t) =A\sqrt{2}e^{\sqrt{2}t}-B\sqrt{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}t}.$$ Now by hypothesis there is $t_0$ such that $x(t_0)=1$ and $v(t_0)=0.$ Replace that in the two equations and sum them to find $1 = 2Ae^{\sqrt{2}t_0}$, hence $A =\frac{1}{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}t_0}.$ Now make a substraction and you find similarly $B = \frac{1}{2}e^{\sqrt{2}t_0}.$ Finally $$x(t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{\sqrt{2}(t-t_0)}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-\sqrt{2}(t-t_0)}=\cosh(\sqrt{2}(t-t_0))$$ and $$v(t) =\sqrt{2}\sinh(\sqrt{2}(t-t_0)).$$ Now, if $x=3$ we find $t =t_0\pm\frac{\cosh^{-1}{(3)}}{\sqrt{2}}.$ Injecting this in $v$ you finally find $$v(t) = \sqrt{2}\sinh(\pm\cosh^{-1}(3)) = \pm 4.$$

Answer (score 2):

What your teacher means is that $\int_{v(x=1)}^{v(x=3)} v dv = \frac{v(x=3)^2}{2}$ since $v(x=1)=0$.

To really make sense of all that, you would need to use differential forms. You can say that $v$ and $x$ are functions defined on the phase space of your problem.

And actually in both integrals, you really integrate differential $1$-forms over a *path* in this phase state, which is the path of your particle between position $x=1$ and $x=3$. Now since $xdx$ and $vdv$ are exact differential forms, it only depends on the integral bounds, meaning the points of the phase space corresponding to the position $x=1$ and $x=3$ of your particle, and this gives the above formulas.

Basically, what you can remember is that it *does* make sense, but the maths behind are a little bit tricky, so when in physics class you can freely use those tricks without worrying too much about the rigourous definitions.

Note that the fact that $2vdv = d(v^2)$ is an exact form is essential to the process, it is very similar to how you can compute the work of the gravity force in a mechanics problem simply by knowing the final variation of height, without worrying about the actual path of your object.

Comment: Hmm I kind of understand what you're saying (I barely studied differential forms: just basic concepts, so this is pretty new to me). Could you explain the part of $v$ and $x$ being functions defined on the phase space of my problem?

Comment: The phase space of a physical system is basically the space of all possible configurations of your system. It is usually defined as the space of all possible positions and momentums, but it is not always so. In your case, you have a point-like particle evolving on a line, so a logical phase space would be $\mathbb{R}^2$, with $(x,v)$ representing position and speed. Then $x$ and $v$ are trivially functions on your phase space : the first and second projection. And the movement of your particle defines a path in this phase space over which you can integrate differential forms, such as $vdv$.

Comment: Ohhh I think I understand what you mean: you're saying I should view this ODE as the system $$\left[\begin{matrix}x' \\
v'\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}v\\ 2x\end{matrix}\right ]$$ then my $x$ function describes a curve in the phase plane ($xv$-plane, and I can integrate it there).

Comment: It's certainly a way to think of it, yes !

Comment: Ohhh, also, here I can see that $v(x=1)=0$ completely determine the solution, as the curves in the phase plane don't intersect, thanks a lot!!

Comment: Also, if you look at energy, you find $E = \frac{1}{2}v^2 - x^2$, so since energy is conserved, you get that the particle travels on a hyperbola in the phase space. Thus you get the famous result : for a harmonic oscillator, the phase space is a disjoint union of conics, each corresponding to a certain level of energy, and trajectories on the phase space are along these conics. Here you get hyperbolas because your system is repulsive, but for a more classical attractive oscillator, you would get ellipses.

Answer (score 1):

The differential equation implies that 
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \left((\dot x(t))^2 - x(t)^2 \right) = 0 
$$

which implies that  $(\dot x(t))^2 - x(t)^2  = const$. Since $x = 1$ when $\dot x = 0$, the constant must be -1. Therefore if $x = 3$, then $(\dot x)^2 = 16$ and $\dot x = \pm 4$. The solution of the ODE is $x(t) = \cosh \sqrt{2}t$, and indeed $x(t) = 3$ at the values $t = \pm \frac{\cosh^{-1}(3)}{\sqrt{2}}$. At these points, $\dot x = \pm 4$.

Answer (score 0):

Normally those integrations are done with indeterminate boundaries, so

$\int v.dv = \int 2x.dx$

$\implies v^2/2 + c = x^2$, where c is a constant. Then we put the initial condition $v = 0$ at $x=1$.

Then $c = 1$ and we have $v^2/2 = x^2 - 1$

Setting $x = 3$, $v(3)^2/2 = 8 \implies v(3) = \pm 4$

Answer (score 0):

Let me just address your professor's thought process. When he goes from $vdv = 2xdx$ to $\int_0^v vdv = 2\int_1^3 2xdx$, he thinks as follows: It is given that when when $x=1$, then $v=0$, and when $x=3$, then $v=v$ (with an abuse of notation, the $v$ on the left-hand-side is the symbol for velocity, and the $v$ on the right-hand-side is the value of the velocity at $x=3$.

So when $x$ runs from $1$ to $3$, $v$ will run from $0$ to $v$.

This is why the integration bounds $\int_0^v$ on the $dv$ integral correspond to the integration bounds $\int_1^3$ on the $dx$ integral.